# two lines that are perpendicular to a third line do not have to be parallel.

Tags: geometry, 3d

In 3-space, two lines that are perpendicular to the same plane must be parallel. However, two lines that are perpendicular to a third line do not have to be parallel. Explain why. I am having a very difficult time understanding this problem.

Answer (score 2):

[image: 3d graph]
I think this graph will be enough to make you understand this.look at those planes(instead of lines) perpendicular to the xy plane.they are clearly parallel to each other.

Now look at the x,y and z axis.look x and y axis are perpendicular to z axis.but **are they parallel?**

Comment: Wow! Thank you. The picture helped tremendously. But why does that happen?

Comment: happend what?please elaborate your question.

Comment: I see how two lines that are perpendicular to a third line do not have to be parallel but why does that happen?

Comment: because of their directions.To be parallel then their directions must have to be the same or completely opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Given a line in $3D$ and a point on it, there is a plane that passes through that point and is perpendicular to that line. Now in a plane you can have infinitely many lines, choose two which pass through the point and lie in the plane and are NOT perpendicular to each other.

Think about the three axes. Two of them are perpendicular to the third one.